# Problems with RabbitMQ and NestJS. I can't publish a message with nestjs-rabbitmq and NestJS

Tags: rabbitmq, nestjs

I have NestJS 8.0.0 and I'm using @golevelup/nestjs-rabbitmq": "2.2.0.
Basically I have handling messages working fine but I can't send any, I just get a "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isConnected')" error.

I'm following this approach:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@golevelup/nestjs-rabbitmq#publising-messages-fire-and-forget

This is from a controller which I'm trying to send a message from. I've injected in the AmqpConnection as per instructions

```
constructor(private readonly amqpConnection: AmqpConnection) {}
```

```
await this.amqpConnection.publish(
      // exchange name defined by other service which have subscriber
      'my.exchange.name',
      // routing key
      'my.routing.key',
      queueMessage
    );
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isConnected')\n    at AmqpConnection.publish (LOCAL_PATH\\node_modules\\@golevelup\\nestjs-rabbitmq\\src\\amqp\\connection.ts:423:33)\n    at MessageController.handleMessage 
"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isConnected')"
```

My assumption is that I've done something stupid with the setup. This is backed up by the fact that the app loads correctly and spits out all the correct console messages:
Successfully connected to a RabbitMQ broker
Initializing RabbitMQ Handlers
Successfully connected a RabbitMQ channel "AmqpConnection"
etc etc

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Are you using request scoped dependencies inside of your controller?

Answer (score 4):

I fixed this issue. It was related to the way I had set up NestJS. I was not exporting the RabbitMQModule in the rabbit.module.ts I had created.  Now my module looks like this:

```
@Global()
@Module({
  controllers: [],
  imports: [
    RabbitMQModule.forRoot(RabbitMQModule, {
      exchanges: [
        {
          name: 'exchange-name',
          type: 'topic',
        },
      ],
      uri: 'amqps://rabbitmqservice',
      connectionInitOptions: { wait: false },
      enableControllerDiscovery: true
    }),
    RabbitModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  exports: [RabbitMQModule]
})
export class RabbitModule {}
```

And works fine when injecting the connection into the constructor of my controller as per instructions:

```
constructor(
    private readonly amqpConnection: AmqpConnection
  ) {}
```

Comment: Thank you for adding the solution. I will be trying this soon.

Comment: I have several questions abut this:

1. Why do you HAVE to import the `RabbitModule`?
2. Why if you don't import the `RabbitModule` the `AmqpConnection` is not defined?

Comment: And why there is no explicit documentation in how to inject the connection?

Comment: @Andy95 RabbitModule is an independent entity, AppModule has to import it to know the configurations of the rabbit module.