# nestjs-rabbitmq Node.js package not handling messages

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, nestjs, publish-subscribe

Maybe I am missing a basic thing as I am starting out with Nestjs, but somehow I can't get Nest.js to receive messages in a Pub/Sub pattern using: https://github.com/golevelup/nestjs. I create the Messaging Service like so:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    RabbitMQModule.forRoot(RabbitMQModule, {
      exchanges: [
        {
          name: 'tx-nextor',
          type: 'topic',
        },
      ],
      uri: RABBIT_URI,
      channels: {
        'channel-1': {
          prefetchCount: 15,
          default: true,
        },
      },
    }),
    MessagingModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  controllers: [],
})
export class MessagingModule {}
```

Everything is connecting correctly and I can see the connection and channel in the RabbitMQ admin. After I created a subscriber:

```
@Injectable()
export class ResourceService {
  @RabbitSubscribe({
    exchange: 'tx-nextor',
    routingKey: 'resource.*',
    queue: 'resource-history-resource.*.updated',
  })
  public async updatedHandler(msg: {}, amqpMsg: ConsumeMessage) {
    console.log('Subscribe handler ran');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(msg));
    console.log(`Correlation id: ${amqpMsg.properties.correlationId}`);
    return 'test';
  }
}
```

This also connects:

```
[resource-history] [Nest] 220  - 07/09/2022, 4:30:47 PM     LOG [RoutesResolver] AppController {/}: +8ms
[resource-history] [Nest] 220  - 07/09/2022, 4:30:47 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/, GET} route +3ms
[resource-history] [Nest] 220  - 07/09/2022, 4:30:47 PM     LOG [RoutesResolver] HistoryController {/history}: +1ms
[resource-history] [Nest] 220  - 07/09/2022, 4:30:47 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/history/appointment, GET} route +1ms
[resource-history] [Nest] 220  - 07/09/2022, 4:30:47 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/history/test, POST} route +1ms
[resource-history] [Nest] 220  - 07/09/2022, 4:30:47 PM     LOG [RabbitMQModule] Initializing RabbitMQ Handlers
[resource-history] [Nest] 220  - 07/09/2022, 4:30:47 PM     LOG [RabbitMQModule] Registering rabbitmq handlers from ResourceService
[resource-history] [Nest] 220  - 07/09/2022, 4:30:47 PM     LOG [RabbitMQModule] ResourceService.updatedHandler {subscribe} -> tx-nextor::resource.*::resource-history-resource.*.updated
[resource-history] [Nest] 220  - 07/09/2022, 4:30:48 PM     LOG [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started +11ms
```

But after I do this nothing is logged.
[image]

Although the consumer is connected, all testmessages are staying on the queue:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adding RabbitMQModule to the exports in the Module definition solved the issue for me.

Reference: [Problems with RabbitMQ and NestJS. I can't publish a message with nestjs-rabbitmq and NestJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71474301/problems-with-rabbitmq-and-nestjs-i-cant-publish-a-message-with-nestjs-rabbitm)

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    RabbitMQModule.forRoot(RabbitMQModule, {
      exchanges: [
        {
          name: 'tx-nextor',
          type: 'topic',
        },
      ],
      uri: RABBIT_URI,
      channels: {
        'channel-1': {
          prefetchCount: 15,
          default: true,
        },
      },
    }),
    MessagingModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  controllers: [],
  exports: [RabbitMQModule],
})
export class MessagingModule {}
```

Also, in the RabbitMQ Admin, make sure the payload has "" in the value, so it would be "test" vs test (sending JSON also should work)

Hope this helps!